# WordPress theme is not displayed properly on other computers

Tags: themes, wp-admin

I am currently working on making an extranet with WordPress. While I was adding content to the site, I noticed that the theme won't be properly displayed when I visit the page from a Windows 10 machine.

This is how the theme looks like from my Debian test machine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGi8H.jpg

And this is how the Windows 10 machine shows the frontpage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkntR.png

It looks like the Windows 10 machine only shows the HTML code which results in the theme not being shown as it should.

The people I asked for help, said that it had to do with either permalinks or with write permissions.

If someone could shed some light on the situation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Look at the browser's error console for error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accessing via an internal IP address? If so, have you set up your wordpress url to be that IP, rather than something like localhost?

Wordpress could be creating incorrect links to external files such as CSS etc.

Comment: My manager told me to change the wordpress and site url which made visiting the website from a Windows machine possible. It's weird though since I have changed it before but that prevented me from going to the admin panel.